# Retrieving a combined result from a drop down but from two different Angular array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options, angular-filters

I am having an issue here and need some direction.  I have a drop down where I choose my selection and it will pull up a matching result from two different Angular data.  For example, I have two angular scopes, one is called `$scope.mSessions` and the other one is `$scope.cSessions`. Each array has different keys except for one where they share the same category and use my  `<select>`tag to pull the common data depending on my selection. So my `<select>` option will have categories like `RED FRUIT`, `YELLOW FRUIT` and `ORANGE FRUIT` and if I choose `RED FRUIT`, it will go through my arrays in `mSessions` and `cSessions` then pull up `"m_category": ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Pineapple"]` and `"category": [{"RED":["YES"]}]`.  I think I should either create a new array that will combine both data into one then do the string comparison or somehow access two different data by selecting one of the dropdowns.  I can't figure out what's the best way to do this.  Please help..!

Here's my code and JSFiddle first http://jsfiddle.net/missggnyc/ujj18nhv/29/

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myFruit">
  <div ng-controller="fruitController">
    <select ng-model="selectedAnswer" ng-options="c.cat for c in mySelection"></select> {{selectedAnswer}}
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Session Name</td>
        <td>M Category</td>       
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="m in mSessions">        
        <td>{{m.name}}</td>
        <td>{{m.m_category}}</td>        
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>C Category</td>
      </tr>
       <tr ng-repeat="c in cSessions ">        
        <td>{{c.category}}</td>        
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module("myFruit", []);
    app.controller("fruitController", function($scope) {
            $scope.mySelection = [
  {"cat": "RED FRUIT",  "m_category": ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Pineapple"], "category": [{"RED":["YES"]}] }, 
  {"cat": "YELLOW FRUIT",  "m_category": ["Banana", "Pineapple"], "category":  [{"YELLOW": ["YES"]}] },
  {"cat": "ORANGE FRUIT", "m_category": ["Peach", "Nectarine"], "category": [{"ORANGE": ["YES"]}]}
  ];
  $scope.mSessions = [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "BD20",
    "m_category": ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Pineapple"]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "CS03",
    "m_category": ["Banana", "Pineapple"]
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "MIS99",
    "m_category": ["Peach", "Nectarine"]
  }];

  $scope.cSessions = [{
    "number": 439,
    "name": "FDFG",
    "category": [{"RED":["YES"]}]
  }, {
    "number": 34,
    "name": "CN",
    "category":  [{"YELLOW": ["YES"]}]
  }, {
    "number": 44,
    "name": "PPP",
    "category": [{"ORANGE": ["YES"]}]
  }];
});
```

Comment: You could `flatMap` together all the category combinations to populate a single array with all permutations of keys, but this doesn't seem useful for what you might be doing. See https://jsfiddle.net/fo0aoc9f/ for an example of how you might do this (though you probably want to use `flatMap` and `uniq` implementations from a performant library like Lodash in production).

Comment: @miqid, thanks for your input.  But I am not really familiar with `flatMap` and `uniq` methods since they're more Java methods.  I also updated my `$scope.mySelection` array since I was missing two categories from dif. arrays.  Please see my updated code.... Also, any JS methods that I can use to make this work?

Comment: Your objective is still unclear to me. Are you trying to simply filter the display of `$scope.mSessions` and `$scope.cSessions` based on what a user has chosen from `$scope.mySelection`? Or, are you trying to generate items for `$scope.mySelection` based on the contents of the other arrays? If the latter, you'll need some way (e.g. common join key) of associating `m_category` or `category` to its respective `$scope.mySelection` item. BTW, those methods aren't specific to Java at all—they're common in functional programming.

Comment: @miqid, I am trying to filter the display of `$scope.mSessions` and `$scope.cSessions` based on the common category that I created such as `"cat": "RED FRUIT" , "YELLOW FRUIT", "ORANGE FRUIT"` in `$scope.mySelection`.   I figured that since `$scope.mSessions` and `$scope.cSessions` have two different names of categories but need to have same category to filter out my results, I decided to create a new category to somehow filter them out.  Does that make sense? So if I choose `"YELLOW FRUIT"` from `<select>`, it will only show `"Banana", "Pineapple"` and `"YELLOW"` from two dif. tables

Comment: @miqid, the part I am confused about is since I have two dif. ng-repeats that are pulling from two dif. data like `$scope.mSessions and $scope.cSessions`, I am not sure how to filter the results by `<select>` option that has a common category in both places.

Comment: Two approaches for you here then—https://jsfiddle.net/ehe8zqr0/ I'd recommend the former in which you use some unique identifier for each item in `cSessions` and `mSessions`. Comparing via category contents directly will always be slower than simply checking the equality of two ID values.

Comment: @miqid, thanks so much for your input. I had to use the latter method and do the string comparisons bc I had a JSON array with a lot of fields without a unique ID. I also had to modify a bit of your string comparison method since my real JSON data was 3D so I used indexof. Your logic was helpful and I got it working!

Comment: @miqid, how do I give u points for ur answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to filter both the tables based on the selection then try the following code:

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/almamun1996/5Ln0d5Lb/14/

***HTML:***

```
<div ng-app="myFruit" ng-controller="fruitController">
 <select ng-model="selectedFruit" ng-options="c.cat for c in mySelection" ng-change="myDropdownChange(selectedFruit)"></select> <br/>
 Fruit Seleted: {{selectedFruit.cat}}
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Session Name</td>
    <td>M Category</td>       
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="m in mSessions">        
    <td>{{m.name}}</td>
    <td>{{m.m_category}}</td>        
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>C Category</td>
  </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="c in cSessions ">        
    <td>{{c.category}}</td>        
  </tr>
</table>
```

***JS (Controller):***

```
$scope.mySelection = [
              {"cat": "RED FRUIT",  "m_category": ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Pineapple"], "category": [{"RED": ["YES"]}]}, 
              {"cat": "YELLOW FRUIT",  "m_category": ["Banana", "Pineapple"], "category": [{"YELLOW": ["YES"]}]},
              {"cat": "ORANGE FRUIT", "m_category": ["Peach", "Nectarine"], "category": [{"ORANGE": ["YES"]}]}
          ];
      $scope.mSessions = [{
            "id": 2,
            "name": "BD20",
            "m_category": ["Apple", "Strawberry", "Pineapple"]
          }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "CS03",
            "m_category": ["Banana", "Pineapple"]
          }, {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "MIS99",
            "m_category": ["Peach", "Nectarine"]
          }
     ];

      $scope.cSessions = [{
            "number": 439,
            "name": "FDFG",
            "category": [{"RED": ["YES"]}]
          }, {
            "number": 34,
            "name": "CN",
            "category": [{"YELLOW": ["YES"]}]
          }, {
            "number": 44,
            "name": "PPP",
            "category": [{"ORANGE": ["YES"]}]
          }
     ];

    let m_myArray = $scope.mSessions;
    let c_myArray = $scope.cSessions;
    $scope.myDropdownChange =  function(fruitSelected){
        let m_myArray_inner = [];
        let c_myArray_inner = [];
        angular.forEach(m_myArray, function(value, key){
            if(areArraysEqual(fruitSelected.m_category, value.m_category)){
                m_myArray_inner = [{'name': value.name, 'm_category': value.m_category}]
            }
        })
        angular.forEach(c_myArray, function(value, key){
            if(areArraysEqual(fruitSelected.category, value.category)){
                c_myArray_inner = [{'category': value.category}];
            }
        })
        $scope.mSessions = m_myArray_inner
        $scope.cSessions = c_myArray_inner;
    }

    function areArraysEqual( x, y ) {
        // If both x and y are null or undefined and exactly the same
        if ( x === y ) {
            return true;
        }
        // If they are not strictly equal, they both need to be Objects
        if ( ! ( x instanceof Object ) || ! ( y instanceof Object ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        // They must have the exact same prototype chain, the closest we can do is
        // test the constructor.
        if ( x.constructor !== y.constructor ) {
            return false;
        }
        for ( var p in x ) {
            // Inherited properties were tested using x.constructor === y.constructor
            if ( x.hasOwnProperty( p ) ) {
                // Allows comparing x[ p ] and y[ p ] when set to undefined
                if ( ! y.hasOwnProperty( p ) ) {
                    return false;
                }
                // If they have the same strict value or identity then they are equal
                if ( x[ p ] === y[ p ] ) {
                    continue;
                }
                // Numbers, Strings, Functions, Booleans must be strictly equal
                if ( typeof( x[ p ] ) !== "object" ) {
                    return false;
                }
                // Objects and Arrays must be tested recursively
                if ( !areArraysEqual( x[ p ],  y[ p ] ) ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        for ( p in y ) {
            // allows x[ p ] to be set to undefined
            if ( y.hasOwnProperty( p ) && ! x.hasOwnProperty( p ) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough methods to do the string comparison! I did use some of the .hasOwnProperty and indexOf to do the string comparison. I like that you covered all scenarios for the string comparison to work and i can use this for another project. Also, the use of 'let' is pretty cool. Never used that before.